# How do I build Kovri from source for OpenBSD?

Tags: kovri, build, openbsd

Is it possible to compile Kovri on OpenBSD from source? If so, what is the process?

Answer (score 2):

Kovri build instructions are on the main Kovri repository here:

https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/blob/master/doc/BUILDING.md

This document will always be the most up-to-date location for build information, so I will not go into the process here.